# from unconstrained to constrained convex optimization

Tags: optimization, convex

Perhaps a silly question, but I have a Legendre-Fenchel-type optimization
$$
\psi^{*}(y) = \max \limits_x \, \langle x,y \rangle -  \lambda \, \psi(x)
$$
for convex $\psi(x)$ and $\lambda > 0$, which I'd like to interpret as a *constrained* optimization.
We also know that $y \geq 0$ and

i) $\psi(x_*) = c$ for the optimal $x_*$.

ii) $\psi(x)$ is increasing in $x$.

I would like to conclude something like
$$
\psi^{*}(y) = \max \limits_x \, \langle x,y \rangle \, \, \, \text{subject to} \,\, \, \psi(x) \leq c
$$
Is such a constrained formulation possible, and if so, what is the most direct argument?

(If need be, I can also assume that $\psi(x)$ is strictly convex.)

Comment: The method of Lagrange Multipliers https://www.math.wustl.edu/~sawyer/handouts/LagrangeMult.pdf provides the link between the two formulations you need.

Comment: Thanks.  I was a bit unsure, because I would be going the other direction (unconstrained to constrained).   But I guess my proof should involve reasoning about the gradient of obj & constraint fns as in the linked sec. 3